# Type mismatch: cannot convert from ViewGroup.LayoutParams to LinearLayout.LayoutParams

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to program a weekly calendar following the exampled posted on:
[How can I create a weekly calendar view for an Android Honeycomb application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355747/how-can-i-create-a-weekly-calendar-view-for-an-android-honeycomb-application)
I have added to the XML file posted there a time marker line that is suppose to be on the current hour. To do that I use:

```xml
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/currentTimeMarkerLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="0dp" >

  <View
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="3dp"
      android:layout_weight="1" />

  <View
      android:id="@+id/currentTimeLineView"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="1dp"
      android:layout_weight="14"
      android:background="@color/dark_blue" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This `LinearLayout` is inside a `RelativeLayout` and both of them inside a `ScrollView`.
I'm trying to "move" this line via programming, by modifying the `layout_margintTop` with these lines:

```java
int dipValue = 720; // we want to convert this dip value to pix
Resources r = getResources();
float pix = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
    dipValue, r.getDisplayMetrics());

LinearLayout lay =(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.currentTimeMarkerLinearLayout);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = lay.getLayoutParams();
lp.setMargins(0, (int) pix, 0, 0);
lay.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

But I get an error in `lp = lay.getLayoutParams()` telling me that it can't convert from `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` to `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But I get an error in lp = lay.getLayoutParams() telling me that it
>   can't convert from ViewGroup.LayoutParams to
>   LinearLayout.LayoutParams.

If the `LinearLayout` is wrapped by the `RelativeLayout` than its `LayoutpParams` are of type `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`(the child takes the `LayoutParams` from the parent). You also, most likely, imported the wrong classes for the `LayoutParams` that you use in the code.

```
LinearLayout lay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.currentTimeMarkerLinearLayout);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)lay.getLayoutParams();
```

Comment: Thank you very much Luksprog, I waste a lot of time because of this issue. Righ now is working very good!