# Add Dynamic View to RalativeLayout

Tags: java, dynamic, view, addition

I'm trying to make a calander app following this tut:
[How can I create a weekly calendar view for an Android Honeycomb application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355747/how-can-i-create-a-weekly-calendar-view-for-an-android-honeycomb-application)

But i need to add a view to the corresponding RelativeLayout but every time i try to run
the app it chrashes.

My fragment .java file:

```
public class Calendar extends Activity {

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class FragmentCalendar extends Fragment { 

    public FragmentCalendar() {
        RelativeLayout activeDay = (RelativeLayout)getActivity(). findViewById(R.id.sundayRelativeLayout);
        View viw = new View(null);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lay = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,2);
        lay.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        viw.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        viw.setLayoutParams(lay);
        activeDay.addView(viw);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendar,
                container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

My fragment_Calendar.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.TJ.rijschool_app.Calendar" 
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="0dp" 
>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/dayLabelsLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/currentMonthRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currentMonthTextView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/medium_dark_gray" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/currentYearTextView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/medium_dark_gray" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/sundayHeaderRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_weight="2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sundayDateTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/medium_dark_gray"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/sundayTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:text="@string/sun"
            android:textColor="@color/medium_dark_gray"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

         <View
            android:id="@+id/dayMarkerView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@color/strong_blue" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mondayHeaderRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_weight="2" >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mondayDateTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/medium_dark_gray"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mondayTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/mon"
            android:textColor="@color/medium_dark_gray"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/tuesdayHeaderRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_weight="2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tuesdayDateTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/medium_dark_gray"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tuesdayTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:text="@string/tue"
            android:textColor="@color/medium_dark_gray"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/wednesdayHeaderRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_weight="2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wednesdayDateTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/medium_dark_gray"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/wednesdayTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:text="@string/wed"
            android:textColor="@color/medium_dark_gray"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/thursdayHeaderRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_weight="2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/thursdayDateTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/medium_dark_gray"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/thursdayTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:text="@string/thu"
            android:textColor="@color/medium_dark_gray"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/fridayHeaderRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_weight="2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fridayDateTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/medium_dark_gray"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fridayTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:text="@string/fri"
            android:textColor="@color/medium_dark_gray"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/saturdayHeaderRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_weight="2" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/saturdayDateTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/medium_dark_gray"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/saturdayTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
            android:text="@string/sat"
            android:textColor="@color/medium_dark_gray"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Had to delete the part about time because file was getting to big to post here.

As you can see the View called dayMarkerView has to be added dynamicly on the day it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to change:

```
        public FragmentCalendar() {
        RelativeLayout activeDay = (RelativeLayout)getActivity(). findViewById(R.id.sundayRelativeLayout);
        View viw = new View(null);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lay = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,2);
        lay.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        viw.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        viw.setLayoutParams(lay);
        activeDay.addView(viw);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendar,
                container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
```

TO:

```
public FragmentCalendar() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = new View(getActivity());

        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendar, container, false);
        View pl = v.findViewById(R.id.thursdayHeaderRelativeLayout);
        View Paper = new View(pl.getContext());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,2);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        Paper.setLayoutParams(params);
        Paper.setBackgroundColor(getActivity().getColor(R.color.strong_blue));

        ((RelativeLayout)pl).addView(Paper);

        //Zet de datum op zondag
        //View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.sundayDateTextView);
        //((TextView)tv).setText("13");

        return v;
    }
```